# Unreal Tournament 2004 crash on start with error message (LockRect failed: D3DERR_DEVICELOST)

Tags: technical-issues, unreal-tournament-2004

I have been playing perfectly UT2004 on Windows 7, but I have formatted my computer, switching to Windows 10, and the game now crashes on start, with an error message that I have never seen before.

> UT2004 Build UT2004_Build_[2005-11-23_16.22]
>
> OS: Windows NT 6.1 (Build: 7600) CPU: GenuineIntel PentiumPro-class
>   processor @ 3403 MHz with 1023MB RAM Video: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960
>   (6175)
>
> LockRect failed: D3DERR_DEVICELOST
>
> History: UD3DRenderDevice::ReadPixels <- UD3DRenderDevice::Present <-
>   UGameEngine::Draw <- UWindowsViewport::Repaint <- UWindowsClient::Tick
>   <- ClientTick <- UGameEngine::Tick <- Level Untitled <- UpdateWorld <-
>   MainLoop <- FMallocWindows::Free <- FMallocWindows::Realloc <-
>   10910191 0 FArray <- FArray::Realloc <- 0*2 <- FMallocWindows::Free

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What solved my problem:

1. Edit (with notepad) the **UT2004.ini** file on UT2004 installation folder. It should be something like this:

> ...\steamapps\common\Unreal Tournament 2004\System\UT2004.ini

2. Uncomment the following line by removing the ; character.

> ;RenderDevice=OpenGLDrv.OpenGLRenderDevice